# How to call one function inside another function Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have one save button by clicking this button it should do to functionalities like converting to canvas and need to be download the image.

```js
     $(document).ready(function(){ 
            var element = $("#bgcolor"); // global variable
            var getCanvas; // global variable
             
                $("#save_btn").on('click', function () {
                     html2canvas(element, {
                     onrendered: function (canvas) {
                            getCanvas = canvas;
                         }
                     });
                });
            
             $("#save_btne").on('click', function () {
                var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                
                var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
                $("#save_btne").attr("download", "revbay.png").attr("href", newData);
             });         
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="save_btn">Save</a>
```

How to call this inside of the another function I tried to call but I need to be click two time on save button which is not correct, please let me know that by one click it whould perform this two functions.

Comment: Is `save_btne` another button, or is it a type-o?

Comment: i have written wrongly that is also save_btn only

Comment: only one id i do have that is save_btn By clicking on this two functionalities should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a single click event, initialize html2canvas at page load, append the url for save after the canvas is saved, use a hidden link and trigger the click on it:

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    getCanvas = canvas;
    $("body").append('<a id="save_btn">save</a><a id="hidden">save</a>');
  }
});
$("body").on('click',"#save_btn", function() {
  var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");

  var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
  $("#hidden").attr("download", "revbay.png").attr("href", newData);
  $("#hidden")[0].click();//trigger the download
});
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/yxmv1rmu/1/

another solution will be to trigger html2canvas at the click event:

```
$("body").on('click', "#save_btn", function() {
  html2canvas(document.body, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      getCanvas = canvas;
      var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");

      var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
      $("#hidden").attr("download", "revbay.png").attr("href", newData);
      $("#hidden")[0].click(); //trigger the download
    }
  });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yxmv1rmu/2/

you can even do it with a single link:

```
$("body").one('click', "#save_btn", function() {
  html2canvas(document.body, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      getCanvas = canvas;
      var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");

      var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
      $("#save_btn").attr("download", "revbay.png").attr("href", newData);
      $("#save_btn")[0].click(); //trigger the download
    }
  });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yxmv1rmu/3/

Comment: sorry its a mistake both are having same id save_btn

Comment: it is performing only one function converting to canvas not downloading..

Comment: it is downloading empty page but images content which im writig which is not downloading, please let me know that issue.

Comment: that means getCanvas is empty

Comment: no it should convert to canvas first then need to be download same

Comment: urs is working but empty canvas is coming.. from yesterday im trying to solve this but couldnt be

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on this small example both calls are running, the problem has to be different. [Example JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/j1q15fzx/1/)

HTML

```
<input type="button" id="save_btn" value="CLICK ME"/>
<p id="result"></p>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $("#save_btn").on('click', function () {
    $("#result").append("<br>FIRST RAN")
  });

  $("#save_btn").on('click', function () {
    $("#result").append("<br>SECOND RAN")
  });         
});
```

As you can see both *onclick* methods execute.

Regarding the update of your code:

I would probably try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  var element = $("#bgcolor"); // global variable
  var getCanvas; // global variable

  $("#save_btn").on('click', function () {
    html2canvas(element, {
      onrendered: function (canvas) {
        var imgageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
        $("#save_btne").attr("download", "revbay.png").attr("href", newData);
      }
    });
  });        
});
```

Comment: haan how abt download and one time only i need to be append write. please let me know with my above example which i have written

Comment: Updated. Give it a try

Comment: it si working but caching the memory means if u change the image then also old image only getting download. if im giving background  images then functions are not working.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so seeing your question what I have understood is:

You want to click on 'save_btn' button and then first execute 'html2Canvas' function. Once this is done, you want to execute another function. If you want something like this, I can suggest you to create two separate functions and make use of jQuery deferred as:

```
var element = $("#bgcolor"); // global variable
var getCanvas; // global variable
var $flag = $.Deferred();   //Deferred object

//Now, do event handling as:

$("#save_btn").on('click', function () {
    fun1();
    fun2();
});

function fun1(){
    html2canvas(element, {
     onrendered: function (canvas) {
            getCanvas = canvas;

            //This is a deferred object. Resolve this whenever you want according to your condition
            $flag.resolve();
     }
    });
}

function fun2(){

    //As soon as $flag deffered object is resolved. This statement will be executed
    $.when($flag).done(function () {
        var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
        $("#save_btne").attr("download", "revbay.png").attr("href", newData);   
    });
}
```

Comment: it is nor converting neither downloading function2id is save_btn please let me know correct one. i tried but it is not working.

Comment: Please check this fiddle.
It uses juqery and html2Canvas.
May be it could help.

https://jsfiddle.net/d9uz8n8m/

Comment: In case, you want to download instantly on single click, trigger jquery click manually:

https://jsfiddle.net/d9uz8n8m/1/